# A message from a good man?

Tags: pattern, cipher

Walter received a coded message from his friend Saul. Walter is accustomed to encrypted communication, it is a must in his line of business. However, this time Saul didn't use any of the prearranged ciphers. Perhaps they were compromised. Anyway, Walter started cracking the new cipher right away and it didn't take him long before he figured it out. He circled a couple of numbers (shown in bold) and suddenly ran away without reading the rest of the message.

> 109  **44**   **7**  95  **26** 100 **110**  61
> 73  16  19  69   7  91  18  10
> 8  95  74  81   3  42   2 101
> 94   1  52  63  53  21  34  56
> 99  85 101  51   7  41  71  34
> 4  85 111  78 109 106  53   2
> 87  92  10  54  16  49  32  84
> 20  53   2  17  75  72  45   2

What was the full message?

Hint:

> [image: Breaking Bad]
>  <sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/61/Breaking_Bad_title_card.png))</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numbers represent

> chemical elements

and he only circled the bold ones because

> you only take the elemental abbreviations in the prime-numbered positions.

The full message is:

> RUN FEDS KNOW HEISENBERG IS HERE